# Sound effects for marble run animation?

Tags: sound-effects, animation

I've got a wooden marble run animation (made in Blender), but am struggling to find some good SFX for the sound design. Has anyone come across a good collection? Rolling balls on wood, around corners, down ramps, hitting (wooden) obstacles, that sort of thing.

[I've found a few on Pond5, but it's (for me) pretty expensive, so a little cheaper is preferred if possible.]

I've also looked on:

- Pixabay
- FreeSound
- Envato Elements
- Boombox (Ae plugin)
- Animation Composer (Ae plugin)

Thanks for any help you can give,

Andy (:

Comment: We're not really here to find offsite resources for you - that's what google's for. We could help you make it yourself, if you tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: DIY in a nutshell. Get a marble run. Take the best mic you can get within your budget (good mobile phone can do), place it on stand. Place the MR in a really silent room with little reflections on walls, floor and ceiling (if possible), use carpets etc. Start recording. Let marble run. Do not make any sound, breathe silently. Check recordings. (Repeat.) Try different MR and recorder positions, like floor, table. Try different distances between MR and recorder, start with distance between MR and a child playing with it. Edit / cut the best recordings (Audacity should provide anything you need).

Comment: Hi @philburns - thanks! I hadn't actually considered this, but it's a good possibility. Not for this project, as I have a deadline that won't allow the setup for that, but I'll try it in future (I seem to use rolling balls a lot). We have some freakin' noisy neighbours above that I'll have to wait out, but I guess that's how it has to be. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin - I'm new here, so not entirely sure what the deal is, but I assumed sound designers would know about sound design resources from around the internet and wouldn't mind sharing info on where they find the good stuff. Is that a different forum?

Comment: Sound designers make & record production sounds. They don't cadge them off the interwebz ;))

Comment: Hi Andy, yes, Stack Exchange is very much aimed at not being a forum at all, but to give specific answers to specific questions in scope, so asking how to make a sound effect is on topic; asking where on the internet to find a sound is not.

Comment: Hi @RoryAlsop, thanks for clarifying. To motion designers like myself, 'sound design' will often mean creating the sound of the animation from pre-made clips, not designing the sound from scratch. Is there another place to ask questions like this on SE, or should I stick to program specific stacks like Blender?

Comment: Generally asking for where something is to be found on the Internet is off topic across all of SE. There are a couple of exceptions, including Software Recommendations Stack Exchange for example, but it just doesn't fit the SE goals. A search engine or forum will probably be what you need.

Comment: OK, thanks - I'll stick to specific questions on here